# Using Complex Join

Tags: sql, left-join, outer-join

I need to fetch a list of Participants for an event. 
An event can be tagged for some countries and regions.

A Participant can register with their interest area (Countries and regions). Interest Area(s) are being used as an option for the participant to filter the events they need.

Interest Area filter can be applied for both countries and region as well as either one of them. Participant can also select this option as :

Countries 'AND' Region  >> Both filters need to be matched

---

Countries 'OR' Region   >> either filters need to be matched

As Soon as an event releases, All MATCHED PARTICIPANTS will be notified about the event.

USED TABLES and their O/P-

```
Select * from CountryMaster
ID          CountryName
1           China
2           Russia

Select * from RegionMaster
regionID    Region
1           North
2           South

Select * from EventMaster
ID          Name
1           Event 1
2           Event 2

Select * from EventCountry
RecID                                   EventID     CountryID
1                                       1           1
2                                       1           2


Select * from EventRegion
RecID                                   EventID     regionID
1                                       1           1
2                                       1           2

Select * from ParticipantMaster
ID          Name        SelectionCriteria
1           Louis       AND
2           Frank       OR


Select * from ParticipantCountry
RecID                                   ParticipantID CountryID
1                                       1             1
2                                       1             2

Select * from ParticipantRegion
RecID                                   ParticipantID regionID
1                                       1             1
2                                       1             2
```

Please guide me to accomplish this.

Comment: Please include any queries that you have tried to solve this?

Comment: You will need **multiple** `JOIN`s, but I do not see any of them to be *complex*.

Comment: thanks for the reply, but how to use the 'AND' & 'OR' conditions?    will it require some optional joins?